# Rails3 / Rails2 - Routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Today I tried to follow the basic "Twitter" tutorial on : 
--> http://www.noupe.com/ajax/create-a-simple-twitter-app.html

But in the midle of the tutorial I have an issue.
It says that you should edit /config/routes.rb and add this piece of code :

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|  
  map.resources :posts  
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'  
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'  
end
```

It was written a while ago so there are probably incompatibilities with rails3 especially with the new routing synthax.
So I tried to fix changing it in :

```
Standart::Application.routes.draw do |map|
  resources :posts
  match ':controller/:action/:id'
  match ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Where "Standart" the name of the application is.

Comment: And did that not work for you for some reason? ;)

Comment: no if I go on http://localhost:3000/ I get the error : No route matches [GET] "/"

Comment: I stoped the server and then restarted it but now it just says that i'm using the old DSL that was removed in Rails 3.1...bla bla bla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `root` route:

```
resources :posts
root :to => 'posts#index'
```

You should try to avoid those catch-all routes that Rails 2 used. If you need other routes, try to see what fits into resourceful routes and use those, and create specific routes with the Rails 3 DSL for anything that doesn't fit.

Comment: Great! You should mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the outline of a check mark to the left of it. Welcome to StackOverflow!